# What is the difference between お元気に、お元気で、気をつけて？

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases

I want to say hello to a friend I haven't seen for a long time, and end my message with "take care". All of お元気{げんき}に, お元気{げんき}で and 気{き}をつけて mean "take care", so which one suits my case?
How should I say it?

And I want to distinguish them clearly.